# SSL Connection to Apache server port 443 in CentOS 7

Tags: apache, ssl, centos7

I am trying to set up an Apache server on CentOS. Following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7) up to the step "Create Virtual Host". Here I replace "80" with "443":

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

Note that I do not configure `firewalld` as per that article, though.

In the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file, I also change the `Listen 80` line to `Listen 443`.

The I start the server with :

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

I check the deployment with

```
wget https://my_dns
```

I get this error:

```
Resolving my_dns (my_dns)... xx.xxx.xx.xxx
Connecting to my_dns (my_dns)|xx.xxx.xx.xxx|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

If I try (test port 80)

```
wget my_dns
```

I get `Connection refused`, which makes sense.

So, it appears the server is on port 443. But what is this SSL issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: please show me the complete conf of virtualhost

Comment: and add http and https in firewall if you are using default ports

Comment: and you must config `SSL` certificates if want to use https

Comment: Configure SSl-  https://serverfault.com/questions/744960/configuring-ssl-with-virtual-hosts-under-apache-and-centos

Comment: @You'r right, it's the SSL configuration that I need to set up. Thanks for the link. Closing this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Listening on port 443 does not imply that you are using SSL. You can listen for HTTP requests on any port you specify. Does this work?

```
wget http://my_dns:443
```

Comment: No, I get this error ```HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden```.

Comment: This is really more of a troubleshooting tip than an answer.

Comment: As per @Indian's suggestion, I need to configure SSL. Thanks for the the response. Closing this thread.